# On iOS, can one run a background app that periodically samples the gps every 2 minutes?

Tags: ios, gps, background-process

Can I have my app, when open in background, not focused, sample the GPS periodically, say every 1 minute?

is that the same as what GPS navigators do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS provides notification on location change to the apps that are registered for the notification. I think this is the one you are looking for. Have a look at "Tracking the User’s Location" section in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html